# download file from database through browser in java desktop (non web)

Tags: java

is it possible to download file from database through browser (ex: mozilla,chrome) in java desktop application (non web app) ? can you explain me with an example code ?
thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, it's possible; no, we won't write the code for you. That's not how this site works. Show what you've tried, and we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: It's not very clear (at least to me) what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to download through a browser if you have a java desktop app? Please edit your question to try to make it more clear what you are after. But as Marc said, StackOverflow is for helping people who help themselves. If you haven't tried anything you are unlikely to get much help here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Desktop#browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) wherein you just specify the URI of that file (exactly the one as you would enter in the address bar of a normal webbrowser).

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://example.com/download/file.ext"));
```

The other side has just to set `Content-Disposition: attachment` on this response to force a *Save As* dialogue (and of course fill the response body with the necessary data from the DB).

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is available through a browser should be available to a Java desktop app.  At least unless the server (e.g. Google) goes to measures to block 'programmatic access'.

> can you explain me with an example code?

Sure, adapted from the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // imagine a DB is preparing/serving this - same difference.
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(-1);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```